# How can I create JSON string from model data Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, struct, codable

How can I create JSON string from other model data?

I am looking to create json string from data but not with success.

Results I am getting in array and then I have used For Loop to pass to AppointmentDownloadModel for json creation.

How can I pass data AppointmentDownloadModel and create JSON String.

Data Receiving Model:

```
struct ResponseData: Codable {

    let appointments : [Appointment]?
}


let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let response = try decoder.decode(ResponseData.self, from: result! as! Data)
self.appData = response.appointments
for everyApp in self.appData! {

}
```

Want to pass response data to this model:

```
struct AppointmentDownloadModel: Codable{
    var appointmentModel: Appointment
    var progress: Int = 0
    var failedList: [Int: String] = [:]
    var isFinished: Bool = false
}
```

**Final need to create this string:**

```
{"appointmentModel":{"appointmentHour":"12:00","backgroundColorDark":"#556f7b","backgroundColorLight":"#cfd8dc","controlHour":"","date":"2020-06-01T12:00:00","heatingType":"b","id":15469622,"isProjectManual":false,"projectFirmName":"Miray Doğalgaz (Erhan Şahin)","projectName":"KÖKSAL ÇOŞKUN-+D1+D3+D5","projectType":"k","subTitle":"18137 902179436-18137-408352"},"failedResourceList":[],"isFinished":false,"progress":0}
```

Comment: @vikingosegundo  updated with appointment model.

Comment: Why is everything optional in your structs? Don't make properties optional unless it is really needed.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson actually data comes from back end sometimes properties have values and sometimes not. So thats why I have set them optional.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert JSON to String in ios Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370541/how-to-convert-json-to-string-in-ios-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following decodes the json example and create new AppointmentDownloadModel objects which are then encoded to Data (and converted to a string)

```
var models = [AppointmentDownloadModel]()

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let response = try decoder.decode(ResponseData.self, from: data)
    if let appointments = response.appointments {
        models = appointments.map { AppointmentDownloadModel(appointmentModel: $0)}
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
do {
    let modelData = try encoder.encode(models)
    let jsonString = String(data: modelData, encoding: .utf8)
    print(jsonString)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thank you first of all. I have implemented your code. it gives me `print(jsonString)` 

`[{\"isFinished\":false,\"appointmentModel\":{\"projectName\":\"HASAN ARSLAN\",\"id\":15473662,\"subTitle\":\"52792 \",\"appointmentHour\":\"09:00\",\"projectDistrict\":\"GEBZE\",\"projectFirmName\":\"Dipos 4 Test Firması\",\"date\":\"2020-06-01T09:00:00\",\"backgroundColorLight\":\"#cfd8dc\",\"backgroundColorDark\":\"#556f7b\",\"heatingType\":\"b\",\"isProjectManual\":false,\"controlHour\":\"\",\"projectType\":\"i\"},\"failedList\":{},\"progress\":0}]`

Comment: In my question please check `Final need to create this string:`
I need like this how can I achieve that

Comment: You have that string, it's just when it is printed you see all the \